# How do i play song back once i have MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

```
NSArray * songs = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[MPMediaQuery songsQuery] collections]];

for (MPMediaItemCollection * item in songs){

    NSString * persistentID = [[[item representativeItem]             valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID] stringValue];
    // Do something with it.
    ??? 

}
```

How do i play song back once i have MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID?

Answer (score 5):

```
//Your song id NSString *songID;

MPMediaPropertyPredicate *predicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:songID forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID];

MPMediaQuery *mySongQuery = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init]; 
//finding songs for predicate 
[mySongQuery addFilterPredicate: predicate];

//add songs to queue
[musicPlayer setQueueWithQuery:mySongQuery];

[musicPlayer play];
```